# Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong with this structure?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to call a function from my .kv but I cannot find the correct way to reference a function outside the function that draws the widgets. I've tried root.dostuff parent... self... MyApp... App... I could put the function into the Widgets class, but that breaks other stuff...

MyApp.py

```
class Widgets(Widget):
    pass

def dostuff(x):
    print(x)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global w
        print("Build")
        w = Widgets()
        return w

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

MyApp.kv:

```
Button:
    text: "Press Me"
    on_press: dostuff(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the correct way to reference a function outside the function that
>   draws the widgets.

You can also `define on_press() outside the kv file`:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

def dostuff(x):
    print("x is %s" % x)


class MyButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        dostuff(22)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyButton()

MyApp().run()
```

my.kv:

```
<MyButton>:
    text: "Press Me"
```

Or, with `on_press() inside the kv file`:

my.kv:

```
<MyButton>:
    text: "Press Me"
    on_press: self.dostuff(10, 20)  #Look in MyButton class for dostuff()
```

---

```
...
...

class MyButton(Button):
    def dostuff(self, *args):
        print(args)

...
...
```

> I've tried root.dostuff parent... self... MyApp... App.

Here's how `root` and `app` work in a kv file:

my.kv:

```
<MyWidget>: #This class is the 'root' of the following widget hierarchy:
    Button:
        text: "Press Me"
        on_press: root.dostuff(20, 'hello') #Look in the MyWidget class for dostuff()
        size: root.size  #fill MyWidget with the Button
```

---

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def dostuff(self, *args):
        print(args)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

MyApp().run()
```

Or, you can `put the function inside the App class`:

my.kv:

```
<MyButton>:
    text: "Press Me"
    on_press: app.dostuff('hello', 22)
```

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyButton(Button):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def dostuff(self, *args):
        print(args)

    def build(self):
        return MyButton()

MyApp().run()
```

> I could put the function into the Widgets class, but that breaks other
>   stuff...

Well, don't let the function do that.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems. The first is that the function `dostuff` isn't defined in the kv file. You can import it with `#:import dostuff MyApp.dostuff` or make it a method of e.g. the app class and call it with `app.dostuff()`.

Also, your kv file isn't actually loaded. To have it be loaded and you don't display the button it would produce, so your example wouldn't actually demonstrate your problem. Name the file `my.kv` to have it loaded automatically, and don't return anything from the build methd to have your Button used as the root widget.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Ok I've put 'dostuff' into the App class, but it doesn't like the variable 'x' when I call it with app.dostuff(1) ?

Comment: Did you miss out the self?

Comment: Where from, it doesn't want to take it in the kv when I call it, or anywhere in the class? I've now tried converting it to a function, and importing it into my kv, but now it's complaining that w (the widgets) don't exist. This is the vicious circle I always seem to end up, I'm definitely missing the point somewhere ;)